# MAgento top-nav bar

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am working with the free redtheme to make a website. This is my first week into magento and designing any website. I have installed and started having a look at magento admin interface.
I am not sure how to get top navigational bar working. Which files needs to be changed to get a top nav bar.
While googling and reading a few articles I found that top.phtml file and added my

tags with menus. But they don’t seem to work. {{ maybe this is why everyone is saying magento is slow }}

Finally got it working but now unable to get drop down menus. Can anyone help with this. Which files do i need to edit to get a drop down horizontal menu.

My next question is regarding red theme. I installed the theme and was playing with it. Trying to get the banner using the red theme user guide pdf but couldnt find the add new banner option anywhere.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a top navbar in Magento, you need to add categories to your site in Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories. Once you have a few categories in the system, the top nav bar will appear.

The banner system is part of Magento Enterprise's Rich Merchandising Suite. I'm not sure there is an analog in Community Edition.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe,
It was a great help. But I tried defining the categories in the manage categories tab but they don't show up. Then after googling a bit i tried editing the top.phtml file located in app>design>>frontend>>default>>THEME>>emplate>>catalog>>navigation>>top.phtml
and added the menu iems I want. and they show up but I m still not sure how to get sub menu's..
I want Home, Products, Store, Contact Us and under each I have few sub menus...How can I do this.
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Sorry, the answer really is to add categories. The entire top navigation was built for the store categories. You may want to revert your top header templates in case you accidentally removed it. As such, the way to get submenus is to create subcategories.